# How to greyout dc.js dataTable

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Current implementation of dc.dataTable redraws the table and shows only the selected group.

Is there a way to highlight rows belonging to a group and thus greying out unselected rows instead of eliminating them?

Comment: It's a good idea, however I can't see how the current crossfilter interface would support this. Basically the API communicates only through filtering and excluding records. There is nothing to query if a record is included or to return excluded records. You could maybe use [dimension.top](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-dimension_top) and [crossfilter.all](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-crossfilter_all) but it would be messy.